# Unable to play rtsp using videoview in android

Tags: android, rtsp

I have set up a RTSP server using VLC. then I write an app,this is my code:

```
package com.ashley.work;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.net.Uri;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.VideoView;  


public class TestPlayRTSP extends Activity {

Button playButton ;  
VideoView videoView ;  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_play_rtsp);

    videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);  

    playButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
    PlayRtspStream("rtsp://140.xxx.xxx.xxx:8554/");  
    }  
    });  


}

private void PlayRtspStream(String rtspUrl){  
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(rtspUrl));  
    videoView.requestFocus();  
    videoView.start();  
}  

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_test_play_rtsp, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and I already set the permission. but this still can not play. nothing happend after I click the button. But if I replace the rtsp with other this two:

1. rtsp://218.204.223.237:554/live/1/66251FC11353191F/e7ooqwcfbqjoo80j.sdp
2. rtsp://v5.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnhycnrJQ8qmRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYPj_hYjnq6uUTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp

the app will play correctly. can any one tell me why? and is there any solution to play the VLC stream???

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Android really only supports mpeg 4 encoded baseline profile with the MOOV atom set correctly. Newer devices support other methods (HLS & higher profiled mpeg4 types) but not all device will work that way.  Your rtsp stream must be encoding using the base line profile.

If you open your RTSP stream in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org) and open your network stream and then MEdia Information you can see what codecs your stream is using for audio and video

Here is more definitive info on android and supported media  : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations

Comment: is vedioview supported media the same as MediaPlayer? If I try MediaPlayer the result will be the same?thank you!

Comment: "your rtsp stream must be encoding using the base line profile"
How i do this ?