# Android RTSP live streaming with videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp, codec

I have an app which shows live streaming of a channel. I was using HTTP at first but now I want to use RTSP because is is supposed to work on more devices. Anyway, my RTSP URI works fine on a 4.3 device. However it does not work on a 2.3.5 device. I only get audio and not video on the 2.3.5 device. Anyway I thought it was a codec problem, so I found a video that played well on both devices and compare their formats: 
This is for the video that does not play:
[image]
This is for the video that plays well:[image]

I cannot see why one plays fine and one only plays the audio. I think is not a code problem as I have been using any possible solution I could find online.

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13291910/782870
Maybe it's related to the problem you're facing

Comment: Yes I have; however I am not responsible for the videos and I cannot change anything in their format. Do you think that there is any chance   that the video resolution has anything to do with it? Because is probably the only difference i can find between the videos..

Comment: I think it's possible since others are experiencing the same problem with higher resolution using rtsp. I also encountered that before, and we cannot modify the video format before streaming. The 2 options we had was to go back to http or use ffmpeg and ndk.  But I am not quite sure if it's the best solution for your case.

Comment: http does not work on devices older than 3.0. ffmeg looks like a lot of job and I have just started working with android development and media and i'm not sure how hard is going to be for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was the resolution of the videos; All devices support up to 480 x 360 px in SD and only some of the devices support up to 1280 x 720 px in HD.